# Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. Prove a subspace in $B(X,Y)$ is open.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, Prove that $O=\{T \in B(X,Y):T^*(Y^*)=X^*\}$ is open in $B(X,Y)$.
(note:$B(X，Y)$ is the set of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ .)
i have no idea how to prove open for a set of operators, should I consider open ball? I hope get proof of this question, thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want $T^*$ to map all of $Y^*$ to a particular $x^* \in X^*$?  That certainly won't happen if $x^* \ne 0$, and if $x^* = 0$ it won't give you an open subspace.  In fact no linear subspace of a Banach space is open unless it's the whole space.

Comment: @Robert Israel  sorry my bad , I typed the question wrong, T*  map whole space Y* to whole space X*, is not particular x* ∈ X*

Comment: Hint 1: $T^*$ is onto iff $T$ is an into isomorphism.
Hint 2: The set of into isomorphisms is open in $B(X,Y)$.